# Non clickable button

Tags: javascript, html, css

i've been trying to figure this out by myself the entire night and i just can't make my button clickable... i would keep trying but i'm tired and i need to go to sleep really bad.
the code is mostly pasted.
i'm really bad at this kind of stuff
don't judge the the bad code...
but i need this button really bad so i can redirect to my welcome page.
the button code itself works, the problems is its conficting with the other stuff and makes it non clickable.
so... here's the full index page of my site with the button that doesn't work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.a {
  text-align: center;
</style>
</head>

<body>
<style>
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
</style>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>    
<div class="a">
<button onclick= "location.href='welcome'"
button class="button button2">&#10084;
</button>
</div>


<html>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text"></div>
    </div>
    <font face="Sarpanch" color="white" size"10" class="message">
    </font>
    <font face="Play">
    </font>
    <font face="Play" class="cn">
    </font>
<div class="clouds">
</div>
<iframe width="1" height="1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F2CXCbz3_Nc?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</html>


<html>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: #000;
}

-webkit-@keyframes we-are {
    from {scale: 1.1;}
    to {scale: 0;}
}

@keyframes we-are {
    from {scale: 1.1;}
    to {scale: 0;}
}

-webkit-@keyframes fadeIn {
   0% {opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 1;}
} 

@keyframes fadeIn {
   0% {opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 1;}
} 

@keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-twink-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:-10000px 5000px;}
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position:0 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}
@-ms-keyframes move-clouds-back {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position:10000px 0;}
}


.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
.text {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  font-family: Iceland;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.5em cyan, 0 0 0.5em cyan;
  
}
.dud {
  color: #757575;
}

.animation-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.animation-container span {
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px white;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-name: move;
}


@keyframes move {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100vh);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: none;
  }
}
.buzz_wrapper{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  margin:180px auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 0 0; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat ;  
        background-size:cover;
        overflow : hidden;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:100px;
}
.scanline{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  background:#000;
  height:4px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  opacity:0.1;
}
.buzz_wrapper span{
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:'Courier new', fixed;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.buzz_wrapper span:nth-child(1){
  color:red;
  margin-left:-2px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
.buzz_wrapper span:nth-child(2){
  color:green;
  margin-left:2px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
.buzz_wrapper span:nth-child(3){
  color:blue;
  position:20px 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}
.buzz_wrapper span:nth-child(4){
  color:#fff;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  text-shadow:0 0 50px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
.buzz_wrapper span:nth-child(5){
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
}

.buzz_wrapper span{
  -webkit-animation: blur 30ms infinite, jerk 50ms infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  0%   { -webkit-filter: blur(1px); opacity:0.8;}
  50% { -webkit-filter: blur(1px); opacity:1; }
  100%{ -webkit-filter: blur(1px); opacity:0.8; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes jerk {
  50% { left:1px; }
  51% { left:0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes jerkup {
  50% { top:1px; }
  51% { top:0; }
}

.buzz_wrapper span:nth-child(3){
  -webkit-animation: jerkblue 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes jerkblue {
  0% { left:0; }
  30% { left:0; }
  31% { left:10px; }
  32% { left:0; }
  98% { left:0; }
  100% { left:10px; }
}
.buzz_wrapper span:nth-child(2){
  -webkit-animation: jerkgreen 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes jerkgreen {
  0% { left:0; }
  30% { left:0; }
  31% { left:-10px; }
  32% { left:0; }
  98% { left:0; }
  100% { left:-10px; }
}

.buzz_wrapper .text{
  -webkit-animation: jerkwhole 5s infinite;
  position:relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes jerkwhole {
  30% {  }
  40% { opacity:1; top:0; left:0;  -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);  -webkit-transform:skew(0,0);}
  41% { opacity:0.8; top:0px; left:-100px; -webkit-transform:scale(1,1.2);  -webkit-transform:skew(50deg,0);}
  42% { opacity:0.8; top:0px; left:100px; -webkit-transform:scale(1,1.2);  -webkit-transform:skew(-80deg,0);}
  43% { opacity:1; top:0; left:0; -webkit-transform:scale(1,1);  -webkit-transform:skew(0,0);}
  65% { }
}
</style>
</head>
</html>


<script language="JavaScript">
class TextScramble {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el
    this.chars = '!@#$%^&*()_-=+{}:"|<>?,./;'
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  setText(newText) {
    const oldText = this.el.innerText
    const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => this.resolve = resolve)
    this.queue = []
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const from = oldText[i] || ''
      const to = newText[i] || ''
      const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      this.queue.push({ from, to, start, end })
    }
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
    this.frame = 0
    this.update()
    return promise
  }
  update() {
    let output = ''
    let complete = 0
    for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
      let { from, to, start, end, char } = this.queue[i]
      if (this.frame >= end) {
        complete++
        output += to
      } else if (this.frame >= start) {
        if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
          char = this.randomChar()
          this.queue[i].char = char
        }
        output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
      } else {
        output += from
      }
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = output
    if (complete === this.queue.length) {
      this.resolve()
    } else {
      this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
      this.frame++
    }
  }
  randomChar() {
    return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
  }
}

const phrases = [
  'Click no bot&#227;o para ir pro nosso site',
  '&#10084;',
]

const el = document.querySelector('.text')
const fx = new TextScramble(el)

let counter = 0
const next = () => {
  fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
    setTimeout(next, 1500)
  })
  counter = (counter + 1) % phrases.length
}

next()

'use strict';

var app = {

  chars: ['lixo','ta de hack','NAO PODE CAPS','PODE NADA NESSE SERVER','esse 1Fawkes ta xitado','TEM ADM?','TEM GENTE JOGANDO GRANADA','panela','server lixo','o que e bipe','ta enxergando muito'],

  init: function () {
    app.container = document.createElement('div');
    app.container.className = 'animation-container';
    document.body.appendChild(app.container);
    window.setInterval(app.add, 100);
  },

  add: function () {
    var element = document.createElement('span');
    app.container.appendChild(element);
    app.animate(element);
  },

  animate: function (element) {
    var character = app.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * app.chars.length)];
    var duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    var offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - duration * 2)) + 3;
    var size = 10 + (15 - duration);
    element.style.cssText = 'right:'+offset+'vw; font-size:'+size+'px;animation-duration:'+duration+'s';
    element.innerHTML = character;
    window.setTimeout(app.remove, duration * 1000, element);
  },

  remove: function (element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  },

};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.init);
</script>
```

https://github.com/wizzz3/website/blob/master/site

the site: https://bf4gatserver.com/

Comment: May you put a smaller more concise example in the question itself? Consider using the snippet tool. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, include all *relevant* code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the green button with the white heart then it's a small fix.

When you try to click the button you actually clicking the fixed div that contains all the floating text, because the element is in `position: fixed; z-index: 1`.

The element that holds the button `<div class="a">`, add to it the following css `position: relative; z-index: 2;` and your done!

Hope this is what you needed =]

Answer (score 0):

Add pointer-events: none; to the .animation-container.

Final code:

```
.animation-container {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Why it works? Because all the clicks happened on .animation-container that has position fixed and some other styling which make it be across the entire page.